# host local fonts in vitejs

Tags: reactjs, vite

Im having problems trying to host and use font in vitejs (react vanilla)

the project structure looks like this:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1vGf.png)

i created a public folder and inside are the fonts like:
im hosting the fonts inside: public > fonts > montserrate-regular.woff

and then on index.css im using @font-face in order to use the font but it doesnt work, heres the index.css:

[index.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix3IQ.png)

can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The src tag in @font-face has to be relative, so start off with ./ and not /

And move the font out of public, Vite will bundle it for you iirc